# Problems with installing Calibre on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: calibre

I installed calibre. When i try to open it via console it states

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

I tried reinstalling calibre but it didnt work. Anyone aware of this problem?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Comment: How, exactly, did you install Calibre?

Comment: sudo apt-get install calibre

Comment: Were there any errors during install? What version of Ubuntu are you running? Looks like you are simply missing a dependency (qt5)

Comment: During Installation everything is fine. When i try to start calibre, the error messages occures

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Maybe could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to install from [binaries](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) rather than Ubuntu's apt repository. Please follow instructions there and if you have further problems please update.